# Text message won't clear even after sending the text in chat

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I'm working on a chat box and it's working fine but when we enter the text message and sent it after the message is sent it won't clear automatically. It will remain there even after posting the text, we need to clear it manually.

I have tried to change some code but couldn't solve the issue.

Code which I'm using in this.

```
    <div class="row">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <h3><?php echo sprintf($this->lang->line("conv_with"), $user["username"]); ?></h3>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="main_container clearfix">
            <div class="ibox-content-no-bg">
                <div class="chat-discussion">
                    <?php
                    $last_conv = $last_conv->result_array();
                    $last_conv = array_reverse($last_conv);
                    foreach($last_conv as $message):
                    $activity_thumb = $message["thumb_url"];

                    if($message["thumb_url"] == "" || $message["photostatus"] == 0) {
                        $activity_thumb = base_url() . "images/avatar.png";
                    }
                    ?>

                    <?php
                    if($message["user_id"] == $this->session->userdata("user_id"))
                        $align_message = "left";
                    else
                        $align_message = "right";
                    ?>

                    <div class="chat-message clearfix <?php echo $align_message; ?>" data-id="<?php echo $message["id"]; ?>">
                        <?php
                        if($message["gender"] == 0) {
                            $gender_user_color = "male_color";
                        } else {
                            $gender_user_color = "female_color";
                        }
                        ?>
                        <a class="nailthumb-msg-container" href="<?php echo base_url("user/profile/".$message["user_id"]) ?>"><img width="62" alt="" src="<?php echo $activity_thumb; ?>" class="message-avatar"></a>
                         <div class="message">
                            <a class="message-author <?php echo $gender_user_color; ?>" href="<?php echo base_url("user/profile/".$message["user_id"]) ?>"><?php echo $message["username"] ?></a>
                            <span class="message-date text-muted pm-date" title="<?php echo $message["date"]; ?>Z"></span>

                            <span class="message-content">
                                <?php echo $message["content"]; ?>
                            </span>
                            <span class="message-date-mob text-muted pm-date" title="<?php echo $message["date"]; ?>Z"></span>

                        </div>      
                    </div>
                    <?php
                    endforeach;
                    ?>
                </div>

                <div class="chat-message-form">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <p class="lead emoji-picker-container">
                        <textarea id="pm-write" class="form-control message-input pm-write-answer-textarea" placeholder="<?php echo $this->lang->line("enter_message_here_placeholder"); ?>" name="message"  data-emojiable="true"></textarea> 
                        </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="btn-reply-placeholder">
                        <a class="btn btn-primary btn-send-reply" href="#" data-user-id="<?php echo $user["uid"]; ?>" data-conv-id="<?php echo $current_conv->id; ?>"><?php echo $this->lang->line("send_reply_btn"); ?></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

AJAX

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.nailthumb-msg-container').nailthumb();
    $(".pm-date").timeago();
    $(".message").emoticonize();

    $(".chat-discussion").scrollTop(100000);

    window.setInterval(function(){
        var last_message_id = $(".chat-message:last").attr("data-id");

        // Live refresh
        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "pm/refresh_conv",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {conv_id : conv_id, last_message_id: last_message_id},
            success: function(data) {

                $.each(data.last_messages, function(i, item) {
                    var message = item;

                    var avatar = "";

                    if(message.thumb_url == null || message.photostatus == 0) {
                        avatar = base_url + "images/avatar.png";
                    } else {
                        avatar = base_url + message.thumb_url;
                    }

                    if(message.gender == 0) {
                        var gender_user_color = "male_color";
                    } else {
                        var gender_user_color = "female_color";
                    }

                    if(message.user_id == user_id) {
                        var msg_dir = "left";
                    } else {
                        var msg_dir = "right";
                    }

                    var block_msg = '<div class="chat-message ' + msg_dir + '" data-id="' + message.mid + '">';
                    block_msg += '<a class="nailthumb-msg-container" href="' + base_url + 'user/profile/' + message.user_id + '"><img width="62" alt="" src="' + avatar + '" class="message-avatar" /></a>';
                    block_msg += '<div class="message">';
                    block_msg += '<a class="message-author ' + gender_user_color + '" href="' + base_url + 'user/profile/' + message.user_id + '">' + message.username + '</a>';
                    block_msg += '<span class="message-date text-muted pm-date" title="' + message.date + 'Z"></span>';
                    block_msg += '<span class="message-content">';
                    block_msg += message.content;
                    block_msg += '</span>';
                    block_msg += '</div>';
                    block_msg += '</div>';


                    $(".chat-message").last().after(block_msg);
                    $('.nailthumb-msg-container').nailthumb();
                    $(".pm-date").timeago();
                    $(".message").emoticonize();

                    $(".chat-discussion").scrollTop(100000);

                });
            }
        });
    }, 2000);

    $(".btn-send-reply").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

     $(':input[name="pmwrite"]').val(null);


        var conv_id = $(this).attr("data-conv-id");
        var user_id = $(this).attr("data-user-id");
        var content = $(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor").html();

        $(this).html('<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i>');
        $(this).addClass("disabled");

        var that = $(this);


        $.ajax({
            url: base_url + "pm/send_reply",
            type: 'POST',
            data: {conv_id : conv_id, content: content, user_id : user_id},
            success: function(data) {
                var res = data.result;

                if(res == 999) {
                    alert(not_logged_in_str);

                    that.html(send_reply_str);
                    that.removeClass("disabled");
                } else if(res == 998) {
                    alert(write_something_str);

                    that.html(send_reply_str);
                    that.removeClass("disabled");
                } else if(res == 500) {
                    alert(cant_demo_mode_str);

                    that.html(send_reply_str);
                    that.removeClass("disabled");
                } else if(res == 997) {
                    alert(conv_not_exist_str);

                    that.html(send_reply_str);
                    that.removeClass("disabled");
                } else if(res == 996) {
                    alert(user_blocked_you_str);

                    that.html(send_reply_str);
                    that.removeClass("disabled");
                } else {                                        
                    var avatar = "";

                    if(data.user.thumb_url == null || data.user.photostatus == 0) {
                        avatar = base_url + "images/avatar.png";
                    } else {
                        avatar = base_url + data.user.thumb_url;
                    }

                    $(".pm-write-answer-textarea").val("");

                    if(data.user["gender"] == 0) {
                        var gender_user_color = "male_color";
                    } else {
                        var gender_user_color = "female_color";
                    }

                    $('.nailthumb-msg-container').nailthumb();
                    $(".pm-date").timeago();

                    that.html(send_reply_str);
                    that.removeClass("disabled");

                    $(".chat-discussion").scrollTop(100000);

                }
            }
        });
    });

    String.prototype.replaceArray = function(find, replace) {
      var replaceString = this;
      for (var i = 0; i < find.length; i++) {
        replaceString = replaceString.replace(find[i], replace[i]);
      }
      return replaceString;
    };
});
```

I expect the textarea to be cleared after someone send t the message but actual is the text will remain in textarea even after the message is sent.

Comment: How do you send the text message? using AJAX or a form?

Comment: Post full code please

Comment: I using AJAX to send messages

Comment: Stupid question: you have a lot of code. Is there any part of that code that even tries to handle the clearing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this `$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor")` is your element for your content. since this is the one you called in

`var content = $(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor").html();`

Try clearing this element after success by using this code since you're using a jquery here.

```
$(".emoji-wysiwyg-editor").html('');
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add this line at the start of your AJAX success() function

```
$('#pm-write').empty();
```

Using pure Javascript

```
document.getElementById('pm-write').innerHTML = "";
```

It would look like this

```
 $.ajax({
       url: base_url + "pm/send_reply",
       type: 'POST',
       data: {conv_id : conv_id, content: content, user_id : user_id},
       success: function(data) {
            var res = data.result;

            $('#pm-write').empty(); //Clean the textarea
            //Other code
       }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Using javascript, you can easily achieve this by setting an event listener on the text-area like this

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    var submitBtn = document.getElementsByClassName("btn-send-reply")[0];  
    submitBtn.addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementsByName("message")[0].value = "";
    });
});
```

or in jQuery

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.btn-send-reply').click(function(){
        $( "input[name*='message']" ).val("");
    })
})
```